# The comment could not be saved. No comment_ID on comments

Tags: comments, comments-template

Every time I try posting a comment logged in as an admin, I get the following message:

**[ERROR: The comment could not be saved. Please try again later.]**

But when I actually go to the database, I find that the comment has been saved, but it has no comment_ID AND it shows the comment twice in the database.

When I try posting comment logged out, I get this message:

**[You are posting comments too quickly. Slow down.]**

So it seems each comment is posted double for some reason, and I can't figure out why. What's confusing is that this only happens on the live version on my website, the one hosted local on XAMPP works completely fine.

The only difference is that I'm running Varnish, Breeze, and Cloudflare on the live server. Could any of these be causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was indeed solved by turning on Auto_Increment (A_I) for "comment_ID". Here's how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665571/auto-increment-in-phpmyadmin

In my case, "comment_ID" was not set as a Primary Key and I received an error (1075). It was easily fixed by assigning a Primary Key to "comment_ID". See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198397/mysql-how-to-set-the-primary-key-on-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For some reason, AutoIncrement wasn't turned on on comment_ID on the live server.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your phpmyadmin.
select all the tables.
select the "repair table" option from the dropdown.
It will be solved